# Toggle a button With jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made some media queries to hide the side menu when the window get's too small. The problem is that then I'm not capable of toggling the menu again because it's hardcoded on the css.

So I tried to click the button to hide the sidebar instead. But it clicks multiple times while I am resizing.

What can I do to make a side menu hide when the window is smaller than 991px but still be able to show it again when I click the button??

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(document).width();
  if (width < 991) {
    $('#sidebar-btn').click();
  }
});

$('#sidebar-btn').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggle('visible');
  $('.content-wrapper, .full-page-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper full-page-wrapper');
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: left 1s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  #sidebar {
    left: -200px !important;
  }
  .content-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to add relevant parts of HTML in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag variable keeping the hidden/visible state of the side bar.

```js
var sidebarIsVisible = true;
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(document).width();
  if (width < 991) {
    if (sidebarIsVisible) {
      // Will happen only once now
      $('#sidebar-btn').click();
      sidebarIsVisible = false;
    } else {
      if (!sidebarIsVisible) {
        // Make visible if width is greater than 991 and sidebar is invisible
        $('#sidebar-btn').click();
        sidebarIsVisible = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide the `#sidebar` when `width` is less than `991` using `hide()` jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(document).width();
  if (width < 991) {
    $('#sidebar').hide();
  }else{
    $('#sidebar').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: it's not that simple. I need to hide or send it to the left 200px and move the content wrapper to the left aswell

Comment: @user9430227 so for that I think you are using a class...?

Answer (score 0):

**992px and above-**
Show the `#sidebar`  and hide `#sidebar-btn`

```
#sidebar{
    display: block;
}
#sidebar-btn{
    display: none;
}
```

**For 991px and below -** 
hide the `#sidebar`  and show `#sidebar-btn`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    #sidebar{
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebar-btn{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Now use the toggle side bar on `#sidebar-btn` click

```
$('#sidebar-btn').click(function (){
    $('#sidebar').toggle();
});
```